# Trouble getting some content within a box in a wbpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse the content within a box like container located at the very bottom of [this website](https://www.proxy-list.download/HTTPS) but I don't find their existence in page source. I've tried to create a script to reach them anyway.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.proxy-list.download/HTTPS'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
item = soup.select_one("a#btn3").text
print(item)
```

Output I'm having:

```
Copy to clipboard
```

I'm after this:

```
104.248.115.236:80
104.248.53.46:3128
104.236.248.219:3128
104.248.115.236:3128
104.248.115.236:8080
104.248.184.16:8080
```

This is how that content is visible in that page:

[image]

Comment: The css selector you are using is grabbing an the first anchor tag with id=btn3. This is not the that little text box, it is just that button underneath the list of addresses whose text is Copy to Clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link `https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v0/get?l=en&t=https` (which you can find using dev tools) to get them all like the way I've shown below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v0/get?l=en&t=https'

r = requests.get(url)
for item in r.json()[0]['LISTA']:
    proxy = f"{item['IP']}{':'}{item['PORT']}"
    print(proxy)
```